# Is dictionary the best data structure for this case?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the need to have a

```
Dictionary< long, List<Person> >
```

Person has ID and Value properties.

I want to be able to get the List by an ID and also be able to find a person with a specific ID easily from this collection.

Is `Dictionary< long, Dictionary<long, string> >`

the only good fast way of getting this done? Or is there another simpler or better data structure to use in this case?

EDIT: Also, for a lookup if i ONLY have the person ID then I would still have to loop through the original dictionary to get that value.
 Thanks,

Comment: What is `long` supposed to represent?

Comment: Simple `List<Person>` will do. You can use LINQ to search list for person with specific ID

Comment: @Satpal Wouldn't `myDictionary[Id]` be much faster?  If the lookup by id is done often, I would prefer the `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Khan Supposes the `long` is supposed to be the ID of the `Person`, what is the sense in creating a list for each ID ?

Comment: It's true that using a dictionary would be faster **depending on the size of the list.** You can't make a blanket statement about performance without knowing all the constraints. If there are typically a very small number of entries then performance likely won't be significant enough to matter.

Comment: Hi, I mean List<Person> ... i need to do a fast id lookup on it.

Comment: It sounds to me like you mean `Dictionary<long, Person>`. I'd use what @Satpal has suggested, a `LINQ` query.

Comment: @OmriAharon `Dictionary<long, Person>` is what I was thinking.  I wasn't clear. :)

Comment: @Khan, still OmriAharon point holds

Comment: the exact structure is Dictionary<GroupId, Dictioanry<PersonId, PersonName> is .... if that helps..

Comment: @theOne Can you please edit your questions to be as accurate as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a `Dictionary<long, List<Person>>` (or maybe just `Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<Person>>`)  and *only* change the structure if speed is a *measurable* issue.  Then a lookup would just be:

```
outerDict[listID].First(p => p.ID == personID);
```

A few drawbacks of using `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, Person>>`:

- If the ID of a person changes, you'd need to intentionally move it to a different bucket in the `Dictionary` (there's no framework structure that does this for you)
- If you just want a list of `Person`s, or need to look up people by an attribute other than `ID`, then the structure just makes it a bit harder to traverse the inner collection.

If neither of those is a concern, then `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, Person>>` would definitely be faster, but you won't know how much faster until you try both and measure them.

Based on your edit (and assuming the List ID and Person ID *never change* for a Person), another option may be to load all of the data into a flat list and create lookups by ListID and a dictionary by PersonID:

```
List<Person> people = {load list};
var peopleByListID = people.GroupBy(p => p.ListID).ToLookup();
var peopleByID = people.ToDictionary(p => pID, p => p);
```

That way you can use whatever structure best fits your needs.  There's some additional overhead for creating the lookup and dictionary, so unless you're needing to constantly go back to the original source these would provide significant performance benefit in the searches.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have a two-keyed dictionary.  You need to have two long values to access the value of your dictionary.  Simply create a composite object representing both of these ID values to be the key to your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<long, long>, Person>
```

By using a single flattened dictionary, rather than nested dictionaries, you prevent the fragmentation in memory and limit the dictionary's overhead.  If you would like to improve readability a bit, you can create your own custom object to represent the key (just be sure to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` effectively) instead of using a `Tuple`.

Comment: +1 and thanks Servy, I will look into this as well. Again much appreciated.